# Alpine Docker image with pandas installed on Pipenv

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, pipenv

We need an alpine based docker image that can have pandas package within pipenv

This works.

```bash
FROM python:3-alpine 
RUN apk add g++  && \ 
    pip install numpy
```

But, our process needs the install on pipenv and below fails with error pipenv not found

```bash
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN apk add g++  && \ 
    pipenv install numpy
```

Note pipenv is installed in earlier docker statements. However, even the below fails, with pipenv not found

```bash
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN apk add g++  && \ 
    pip install --user pipenv && \
    pipenv install numpy
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

`pipenv` isn't available because `pip install --user pipenv` installs it in `/root/.local/bin`, which isn't listed in the search path (`$PATH`). The easiest way to fix it would be to install `pipenv` without the `--user` flag. It will then be installed in `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN apk add g++ && \
    pip install pipenv && \                                                     
    pipenv install numpy
```

If you run through the build steps manually, it gives you a warning about this:

- `docker run --rm -ti python:3-alpine /bin/sh`
- `apk add g++`
- `pip install --user pipenv` this shows the warning below:

> WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.